# What's the range of valid source characters in Python 3?

Tags: python

On page 10 of the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), we can find a lexical definition of the string literal.

```
stringliteral   ::= [stringprefix](shortstring | longstring)
stringprefix    ::= "r" | "u" | "R" | "U" | "f" | "F"
                    | "fr" | "Fr" | "fR" | "FR" | "rf" | "rF" | "Rf" | "RF"
shortstring     ::= "'" shortstringitem* "'" | '"' shortstringitem* '"'
longstring      ::= "'''" longstringitem* "'''" | '"""' longstringitem* '"""'
shortstringitem ::= shortstringchar | stringescapeseq
longstringitem  ::= longstringchar | stringescapeseq
shortstringchar ::= <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>
longstringchar  ::= <any source character except "\">
stringescapeseq ::= "\" <any source character>
```

That last line, `stringescapeseq ::= "\" <any source character>`  is important to my question. As is the third to last one, `shortstringchar ::= <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>`.

I've been trying to understand what a `stringescapeseq` is, by creating my own examples/non-examples, and explaining why each is or isn't a `stringescapeseq`...

Examples:

1. `\$`, because it is a backward slash `\` immediately followed by a dollar sign `$`.
2. `\a`, because it is a backward slash `\` immediately followed by a lowercase `a`.
3. `\T`, because it is a backward slash `\` immediately followed by the source character `T`.
4. `\►`, because it is a backward slash `\` immediately followed by the source character `►`.
5. `\\`, because it is a backward slash `\` immediately followed by the source character `\`.
6. `\v`, because a string escape sequence is a backward slash `\` followed by any valid source character, such as `v`, `8`, or `[`, among others.

---

Non-examples:

1. `\`, because it is just a backward slash on its own.
2. `R`, because that is just the uppercase letter `R` on its own.
3. `\7\h`, because it is actually two string escape sequences, `\7` and `\h`, presented one after the other.
4. `\ab`, because it is actually one string escape sequence, `\a` and the letter `b` presented one after the other.

The only problem is, I really have no clue what the full range of source characters is. Is the control character `\newline` a valid string escape sequence? How about `\r\n`? Or `\<insert emoji here>`? I feel like I'm missing some potentially important variations for my examples. Never mind the fact that some of the ones I've already included might be incorrect.

So I'd really like to know what's the complete definition of a source character as it's used in the Python reference. Or a complete list of all possible source characters.

Comment: There is a table listing all recognised escape sequences further down the page on the page you linked

Comment: The second sentence following the grammar in your link says that the source character set is defined by the encoding declaration, defaulting to UTF-8. So I suppose any Unicode character is valid by default. Is that what you are asking about or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington would you say that `\g` is not a `stringescapeseq` then? That's kind of confusing - if the character `g` is not a `<source character>` then it certainly couldn't be used in a string literal, could it?

Comment: @uneven_mark Yes, that sounds kind of right, except it doesn't account for this little bugger here: `shortstringchar ::= <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>`. I think it implies that `newline` is both a string escape sequence and a source character - and I really find that confusing.

Comment: @progner As far as I can tell a backslash followed by a newline would be an stringescapeseq and is completely ignored, as the table of assigned escape sequences shows, while a newline without a preceding unmatched backslash would be neither an stringescapeseq, nor a shortstringchar, but a longstringchar which would be taken literal. A newline as character is part of the source-character set, but it is only part of an escape-sequence when preceded by unmatched backslash.

Comment: @uneven_mark but wouldn't a backlash followed by a newline look like `\\n` in Unix and `\\r\n` on windows? `\n` and `\r\n` sure don't look like source characters to me, they look like string escape sequences.

Comment: `\r\n` is four source characters, that is to say four characters typed in the source code, which form two escape sequences during lexical analysis, which themselves represent a carriage return and a line feed character as part of a string.

Comment: @progner I think, per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#physical-lines both newline encodings are supposed to be considered equivalent as one character/token, but I am not completely sure whether this applies inside literals as well. Also `source character` refers to the physical characters encoded in the file. An escape sequence (in the general sense) is just a sequence of (usually ascii) characters used to represent some other character (e.g. newline) without having to embed that character physically into a string/file.

Comment: Therefore it doesn't make sense to say that `\n` is a source character, physically these are two characters. However, by common convention and in most string literal encodings, these two characters represent a single character when interpreted in that way, the newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the grammar formally states, a `stringescapeseq` is the backslash character followed by any single source character. As the next paragraph states:

> The source character set is defined by the encoding declaration; it is UTF-8 if no encoding declaration is given in the source file;

If you specified that the current source file is in ASCII and you wrote `\`, that wouldn't be an ASCII character and therefore would not be a valid escape sequence. But I really don't understand why you would pretend a file is in ASCII when it's not. Therefore, erroneous character encoding aside, a `stringescapeseq` is made of exactly two characters, the first of which is a backslash. So yes, `\a` is an escape sequence even if it does nothing special, and `\newline` is also an escape sequence.

Once an escape sequence is recognized, it then has to be interpreted. Python works a bit differently from most C-style languages however, in that both the backslash and the following character are added to the string if the escape sequence doesn't carry a special meaning.

As we can see in the table lower in the page, an escape sequence made of a backslash and a newline has the special meaning of... being completely ignored. It's the same as if neither characters were in the source code at all. EXCEPT IN RAW STRINGS, where the escaped newline has no special meaning, and therefore will produce a string with both the backslash and the newline preserved.

Finally, the documentation somewhat contradicts itself. It said that escape sequences were made of exactly two characters, but the table contains escape sequences for octal (backslash followed by 1 to 3 digits) as well as special cases for hexa and unicode characters which begin with `\x`, `\N`, `\u` and `\U`, but must be followed by something valid in order to be replaced - otherwise they throw a `SyntaxError`.